# No internal method call with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl a website. The first call seems ok and collects some data. For every subsequent request I need some information from another request. For programing simplification, I separated the different requests into different method calls. But it seems that scrapy does not provide method calls with some special parameter. Every sub-call won't be executed.

I tried already a few different things:

1. Called a instance method with self.sendQueryHash(response, tagName, afterHash)
2. Called a static method with sendQueryHash(response, tagName, afterHash) and changed the indent
3. Removed the method call and it worked. I saw the sendQueryHash output on the logger.

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
import logging

class TestpostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'testPost'
    allowed_domains = ['test.com']

    tags = [
         "this"
        ,"that"   ]

    def start_requests(self):
        requests = []
        for i, value in enumerate(self.tags):
            url = "https://www.test.com/{}/".format(value)
            requests.append(scrapy.Request(
                        url,
                        meta={'cookiejar': i},
                        callback=self.parsefirstAccess))
        return requests

    def parsefirstAccess(self, response):
        self.logger.info("parsefirstAccess")
        jsonData = response.text

        # That call works fine
        tagName, hasNext, afterHash = self.extractFirstNextPageData(jsonData)
        yield {
                'json':jsonData,
                'requestTime':int(round(time.time() * 1000)),
                'requestNumber':0
        }

        if not hasNext:
            self.logger.info("hasNext is false")
            # No more data available stop processing
            return
        else:
            self.logger.info("hasNext is true")
            # Send request to get the query hash of the current tag
            self.sendQueryHash(response, tagName, afterHash) # Problem occures here

    ## 3.
    def sendQueryHash(self, response, tagName, afterHash):
        self.logger.info("sendQueryHash")
        request = scrapy.Request(
            "https://www.test.com/static/bundles/es6/TagPageContainer.js/21d3cb18e725.js",
            meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']},
            callback=self.parseQueryHash,
            dont_filter=True)
        request.cb_kwargs['tagName'] = tagName
        request.cb_kwargs['afterHash'] = afterHash
        yield request

    def extractFirstNextPageData(self, json):
        return "data1", True, "data3"
```

I expect that the sendQueryHash output is shown but it never happen. Only wenn I comment the lines `self.sendQueryHash` and `def sendQueryHash` out.

That's only one example of the behavior what I don't expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.sendQueryHash(response, tagName, afterHash) # Problem occures here
```

will just create a generator that you do nothing with. You need to make sure you `yield` your `Request` back to the `scrapy` engine. Since it is just a single request that is returned you should be able to use `return` instead of `yield` from `sendQueryHash` and then directly `yield` the `Request` by replacing the above line with

```
yield self.sendQueryHash(response, tagName, afterHash)
```

Comment: Return message is: `2019-10-08 14:04:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'generator' in <GET https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/eyeliner/>`. I did it already before and didn't mentioned it because of the error.

Comment: @H.B. your error suggests you didn't change the `yield` to `return` inside `sendQueryHash`. Did you?

Comment: You solved the problem technically. I don't get the point why? That problem will be direcly connected to another problem. I tried to create a loop by using recursion with function calls. It also didn't work.

Comment: Does the figure [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow) help at all? You need to `yield` from your callback to the scrapy engine. In your above code you  `yield` from a function to your callback, but never from the callback to the engine. Let me know if this isn't clear.